# List has no row in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, list, exception

I have this `saveProduct()` method and i am not able to cover it,

> **Stack Trace**   Class.CustomProductSelectionController.SaveProduct: line 93, column 1
>   Class.TestCustomProductSelectionController.myUnitTest: line 107, column 1

```
 public Pagereference SaveProduct(){

    if(opp.Id == Null && oppId == Null){
        insert opp;
    }

    for(wrappProduct wp : wrappProductList) {
        if(wrappProductList.size() > 0){
            if(WP.selfld != '-1') {
                system.debug('====WP.selfld====>'+WP.selfld);
                //below line number is 93
                pdata = [select Id from PricebookEntry where Product2Id =: WP.selfld];
                system.debug('====pdata====>'+pdata);
                    //tbu = WP.prod;
                    oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
                    oli.PriceBookEntryId = pdata.Id;
                    oli.Quantity = 1;
                    oli.UnitPrice = WP.prod.Price__c;
                    oli.Description = WP.prod.description;
                    oli.SOW__c = WP.prod.SOW__c;
                    oli.PrimaryTechnologyArchitect__c = WP.prod.PrimaryTechnologyArchitect__c;
                    //system.debug('====Primary Architech====>'+WP.prod.PrimaryTechnologyArchitect__c);
                    if(oppId == Null) {
                        oli.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
                    } else {
                        oli.OpportunityId = oppId;
                    }
                    insert oli;
                    if(oppId != Null) {
                       opp.Id = oppId;
                       update opp;
                    }
             } else {
                 apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Please select atleast one product.'));
                 return new Pagereference('/apex/CustomProductSelection');
             }
        }
    }
    return new Pagereference('/'+Opp.Id);  
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
Public class TestCustomProductSelectionController{

Private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    PageReference pageRef = Page.CustomProductSelection;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);       

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert acc;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
    opp.CloseDate = date.today();
    opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
    opp.PrimaryTechnologyArchitect__c = 'Ryan';
    opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
    opp.LID__LinkedIn_Company_Id__c = '123';
    opp.Probability = 10;
    opp.Type = 'New Buisness';
    opp.WinLoss__c = '10';
    opp.LeadSource = 'EMC';
    opp.Assessment__c = 'Yes';
    opp.Budget__c = '500';
    opp.ContractNumber__c = '10';
    opp.Competition__c = 'CNT';
    opp.Competition2__c = 'CSC';
    opp.Competition3__c = 'ICP';
    opp.SOW_Nbr__c = '2';
    opp.BIG_Sow_Number__c = '1';
    insert opp;

    Product2 p = new Product2();
    p.Name = 'Test Product';
    p.Manufacturer__c = 'CDI Consulting';
    p.Price__c = 100;
    p.Description = 'Test Description';
    p.SOW__c = '1';
    insert p;

    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = p.Id,UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
    insert standardPrice;

    Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
    insert customPB;

    PricebookEntry customPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = p.Id,UnitPrice = 12000, IsActive = true);
    insert customPrice;

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);

    CustomProductSelectionController controller = new CustomProductSelectionController(sc);

    CustomProductSelectionController.wrappProduct wrapper = new CustomProductSelectionController.wrappProduct();

    wrapper.index = 1;
    wrapper.selfld = p.Id;
    controller.pdata = [select id from Pricebookentry where Product2Id =: wrapper.selfld limit 1];

    controller.AddProduct();
    controller.delWrapper();
    controller.retrieveProductInfo();
    //below line number is 107
    controller.SaveProduct();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
The error means that your query on line 93: `select Id from PricebookEntry where Product2Id =: WP.selfld` is not fetching any records. So make sure you have created Pricebookentry records satisfying the criteria.

**Approach 2:**
If your functionality/test scenario says that there should not be any record satisfying the criteria, you should change your class CustomProductSelectionController.

Instead of saving the query result into a single variable, catch it in a List of PricebookEntry.

```
List<Pricebookentry> pbeList = new List<Pricebookentry>();
pbeList = [select Id from PricebookEntry where Product2Id =: WP.selfld LIMIT 1];
```

This will not fire the error even if it fails to fetch any records.

Later, just check the size of `pbeList` and proceed with rest of the logic.

```
if(pbeList != null && !pbeList.isEmpty())
{
    oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
    oli.PriceBookEntryId = pbeList[0].Id;
    oli.Quantity = 1;
    ....
    /*Rest of the code*/
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Problems in your code:

1. You have a SOQL inside a for loop. This is a bad practice. You should fire the query before the loop and hold the data in a map and use it inside the loop.

Something like this:

```
Set<Id> selfIds = new Set<Id>();
for(wrappProduct wp : wrappProductList) 
{
  selfIds.add(wp.selfld);
}
Map<Id, Id> selfIdTopbeIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(Pricebookentry pbe : [select Id, Product2Id from PricebookEntry where Product2Id IN :selfIds])
{
  selfIdTopbeIdMap.put(pbe.Product2Id, pbe.Id);
}

for(wrappProduct wp : wrappProductList) {
  if(wrappProductList.size() > 0){
    if(WP.selfld != '-1') {
       //tbu = WP.prod;
       oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
       oli.PriceBookEntryId = selfIdTopbeIdMap.get(wp.selfId);
       oli.Quantity = 1;
       ...
       /*Rest of your code*/
    }
  }
}
```

2. What is `wp.selfld`? Since you are matching with `Product2Id`, so it has to be salesforce Id field I believe. But again you are comparing it with -1 inside the for loop, `if(WP.selfld != '-1')`. If its a salesforce Id, it will never be -1, so no point comparing it.
3. This section:

   `for(wrappProduct wp : wrappProductList) {
   if(wrappProductList.size() > 0){`

So when you are already inside a for loop, you don't have to check for the loop list's size. if the `wrappProductList.size()` is 0, it will anyway not enter your loop.

I hope I pointed out some points to optimize your code. This should help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply Santanu, for Approach 1 i have check the data in debug log and it's working fine as we need in the requirement so, i don't think we need to modify the base controller what do you say ?

Comment: If you dont want to change the controller, then make sure you have proper data created in test class. **Plus** running a SOQL inside a for loop is not a best practice, you will hit governor limits if the `wrappProductList` contains more than 100 records.

Comment: yes. thanks for marking, can you please tell me what i have written wrong in both line that i've mentioned 93 and 107 ?

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope I am clear.